# I can't assign values to a structure with a compound literal

Tags: c, structure

I have declared a structure called ***time***, containing 3 integer members called ***sec, min, and hour***. From there, I define a structure variable of type time called ***today***. If I initialize the variable at this point, everything works      ***struct time today = {3, 4, 5};***    However, if I split this into two steps and try to assign values to the structure variable today with a compound literal, as in:
***struct time today;***      ***today = (struct time) {3, 4, 5};***    then gcc yells and tells me that the second instance of today was already defined. This is pretty much a clone of an example from "Programming in C" third edition, by Stephen Kochan, 2005. It also seems legit from several other websites that discuss structures. Has something changed since C99 or is there something that I am missing. I am running this in Visual Studio Code 1.53 with MinGW.
Thanks

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    struct time
        {   int hour;
            int min;
            int sec;
        };
    struct time today;
    today = (struct time) {7, 5, 9};
    int main (void)
    {
        printf("sec = %i", today.sec);
        return 0;
    }
```

Maybe if I stick with this long enough, I might actually start to understand what I'm doing. I put the structure in global space, so I just put all of the structure stuff there as well. Moving the assignment into the Main makes everything work just fine. DUH. Thanks for being patient with me. Tim

Comment: Post the exact code that causes the error, not a mere description of it.

Comment: Please format your code so that is is readable.

Comment: post your actual code.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If GCC tells you that `time` was already defined, then it was already defined. Do not use `struct time today = (struct time) {3, 4, 5};` for an assignment; that is a declaration. For an assignment, use `today = (struct time) {3, 4, 5};`.

Comment: You can't do random assignments outside of function bodies.  Either `struct time today = { 7, 5, 9 };` (a routine initializer for a struct; use designated initializers if you prefer), or move the assignment into `main()` (or any other appropriate function).

Comment: You also should rename the variable, because `time` is already a function declared in `time.h`.